# web.release.config transform in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Currently, in my `web.config` file I have

```
<configuration>
    <general path="c:\abc\" />
</configuration>
```

I want to change `c:` to `d:` when I publish the release version.

How do I do this in a transform?

The `<general>` section is much much bigger so I don't want to rewrite then entire thing, just that one attribute. Can anyone help?

Update: I created the following web.release.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
  </system.web>
  <General dataFilePath="D:\Data" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(dataFilePath)" />
  <AuditManagement auditPath="D:\Audit"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(auditPath)"  />
</configuration>
```

This had no effect on the final web.config.   It still shows "C:\" where I would want "D:\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use transformation

First you have to create the different enviroments for debug or release, and if you want you can add more.

This tutorial is well explained and tested by me:

http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/working-with-multiple-web-config-files/4100

And here is the official documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

as it is explained in the previous your configuration for the web.config will be:

```
<configuration>
    <general path="d:\abc\" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(path)"/>
</configuration>
```

and then you will have to define the correct path in the Debug and Realease configs, once it's finished you will run the app with one of the configurations you set.

Comment: I tried this and it failed.   No changes made to the web.config.  I updated my question (above) with the changes I made.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding these attributes to the Web.Release.config:

```
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(path)"
```

so your final result should be:

```
<configuration>
    <general path="d:\abc\" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(path)"/>
</configuration>
```